# Laravel: Eloquent all() not returning an array of objects

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to build a simple forum system.

I have a model called Category.php, where I define the table and extend Eloquent.

I have a CategoryController.php which is a resourceful controller, within the index() method, I am doing:

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

Which I assume should return an array of objects. This worked fine on a different project of mine.

However, when I try to run this through a foreach, nothing is echoed. I've tried renaming the controller and the model to ForumController and Form, respectively, and it's worked straight away.

Any ideas? Perhaps the Category name has been reserved by Laravel and is overriding my desired functionality?

**CategoryController.php:**

```
<?php

class CategoryController extends \BaseController {

protected $layout = 'master';

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    $categories = Category::all();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('category.index', array('categories' => $categories));
}
```

**Category.php (model):**

```
<?php

class Category extends Eloquent {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'categories';

}
```

**Category/index.blade.php (view):**

```
@section('content')
<ul>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <li><a href="/category/{{ $category->slug }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@stop
```

My database is set up correctly. When I run $category = Category::find(1); it correctly returns the category with an id of 1, which I can use as an object.

Comment: It feels like you didn't even *try* to `foreach` over the collection, because if you had you'd have found that it works.

Comment: Well no, because I wasn't aware how collections worked within Laravel. Hence i asked here, so how does that warrant a downvote?

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. The downvote was because, honestly, I don't think it's a question that benefits the SO community. The question itself is flawed in that you say "I can't foreach a Collection" when, in fact, you can, so it could actually be very misleading to other people on the network. (Source for reasoning behind downvote based on above at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Well not really, since I tried to run a foreach, but there was no output, so I posted here asking for advice. I then changed the name from "Category" to "Forum" and it worked fine, as you can tell by the comments on the other answers. Which leads me to believe that Category is reserved or something. As it wasn't working as expected.

Comment: In which case, it may be worth editing your question to show the code where you're trying to run the `foreach` (rather than `dd` which doesn't quite work the same as it can inspect objects' private and protected properties, and not the magic ones) so that people can see if there's an issue with your actual `foreach`ing code.

Comment: Fair point, but I still don't think it warrants a downvote. I do however believe it is an issue with using Category as a name for a model and controller, as that's the only thing that's different between my projects.

Comment: I don't think this is due to using `Category` as a model name - let's put it this way, at least 25% of Laravel apps out there will probably have a `Category` model - but possibly due to your code in a broader context. It's good you've edited your post but you still don't give the exact code that fails in a `foreach` - it'd be really useful for us to see that code, in case there's still something odd there. I'm aware you said swapping it out for another model works fine, but still, why not just provide it anyway?

Comment: Also, FYI I'll happily revoke my downvote (assuming SO allows me to) when the question is cleared up sufficiently. I'm not trying to hold you to ransom here on the downvote - you can do what you want with your question - just explaining my personal thinking on these matters.

Comment: I've now edited again with all the information you should need, including the view this time where I actually run the foreach.

Comment: I really don't wanna make a huge comments thread here but we need more info. Exactly how does this fail? Nothing is printed (i.e. `foreach ($categories)` appears to not even get one iteration in) or the HTML is printed but the field on each `$category` don't come out? Also, you don't have any code like `View::share('categories', $someValue)` anywhere do you? That could be the reason behind the apparently-reserved variable name maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `Category::all();`. Laravels `Collection` class implements the following interfaces:

```
ArrayAccess, ArrayableInterface, Countable, IteratorAggregate, JsonableInterface
```

Which means:

```
foreach(Category::all() as $category) { 
    var_dump($category);
}
```

Will work, the `Eloquent\Collection` that is returned extends the `Support\Collection` class, which implements the above interfaces.

Take a look at the `Support\Collection` class in `Illuminate`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, when returning multiple results, Eloquent returns a `Collection` (which is quite common practise among frameworks).

You can convert a `Collection` to other formats using methods like `toArray()` or `toJson()`; but you can also iterate through the `count()` of results using methods like `fetch()`, or fetch specific entries using `get()`

**EDIT**

While you can't iterate directly over the `Collection`, you can convert it to an iterable structure using the `getIterator()` method, which returns an SPL [ArrayIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) object

Comment: Ahh right, that makes sense. The only thing that's puzzling me is that on another project I've done the exact same thing and I can use a foreach to do as I wish, without having to use a method like toArray(). I'm very curious as to why and what can cause this difference.

Comment: I've just carbon copied the model and controller, changed the names for Category to Forum and it's worked fine by calling $forums = Forum::all() and running a foreach on the $forums variable. So it may be that Laravel is somehow, perhaps, reserving the "Category" name? I'm not quite sure.